# running 2 methods asynchronously

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I have 2 methods in onCreate which I need to run one after the other ie...the second method will start once the first method is complete irrespective of how much time it takes.Please help me.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

               populateList();

            // close this activity
            //finish();
        }
    }, 20000);getContactList();
```

populateList() method

```
** public void populateList() {
Log.i("Populate List","Entered");

    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(Common.selectedContactNos.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   displayRecyclerAdapter = new DisplayRecyclerAdapter(DisplayContacts.this);
   LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView_contacts.setAdapter(displayRecyclerAdapter);
   recyclerView_contacts.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
   displayRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}**
```

Comment: post your code of populateList() method

Comment: You can use AsyncTask for the same. Call your another method in the postExecute() method of the asynctask.

Comment: As @VivekMishra said either you use AsyncTask or RxJava2 for that.

Comment: can somebody please post the complete code calling bot methods first getContactList() and then populateList()?

Comment: you can use other mechanism for showing splash screen, use SplashActivity with timer, and you willn't have handler\asynctask hell

Comment: I thought about that about splash has a timer and I am fetching phone contacts and doing 2-3 tasks on it.how do I figure out how much time is required to fetch contacts?It can be 5 contacts on 1 phone and 500 contacts on another

Answer (score 1):

just use AsyncTask

call TaskOne class like-
 new TaskOne().execute();

```
private class TaskOne extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getContactList(); 
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        populateList();


    }
}
```

Comment: there is no need to create second asynctask you can simply call the other method in post execute

Comment: populateList method did not get called using only 1 asynctask.do I use two

Comment: i want getContactList() to run first and then populatelist as will populateData fetched in getContactList()

Comment: populateList is not working in onPostExecute() method.is it because it populates the recyclerview and should be called in onCreate() Only?

Answer (score 0):

Call both method inside run method with the sequence you want. Replace your code with below code

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    /*
     * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
     * want to show case your app logo / company
     */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity

            populateList();
            getContactList();
            // close this activity
            //finish();
        }
    }, 20000);
```

Comment: But doesn't both methods will be called simultaneously after the time is over ?

Comment: using this methods are called together.I am fetching some data in getContactList() and then populating in recyclerview in populateList so i want getContactList to be called first

Comment: so call getContact list first and then call other method

Comment: i tried like this yesterday and this doesnt work.both are called together